# Woocommerce API v3 - Reviews with custom meta_data

Tags: python, woocommerce

I'm working on a simple script to add new reviews to products using the WooCommerce API (WCAPI).

The core functionality of the script is to read data from a CSV file, process it, and then use the WCAPI to add reviews to products. The primary function, `add_reviews_from_file`, works as expected except for one part: adding meta data to the reviews.

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
def add_reviews_from_file(filename, all_products):
    # Initialize a dictionary to store responses
    product_reviews = {}

    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in reader:
            product_id = row['product_id'] if row['product_id'] else random.choice(all_products)
            random_date = generate_random_date(datetime(2021, 1, 1), datetime(2023, 12, 31))
            review_data = {
                "product_id": product_id,
                "review": row['review'],
                "reviewer": row['reviewer'],
                "reviewer_email": row['reviewer_email'],
                "rating": int(row['rating']),
                "date_created": random_date.isoformat(),
                "verified": 1,
                "meta_data": [{"key": "cena", "value": row['cena']}]
            }

            response = add_review(URL, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, product_id, review_data)

            # Update the dictionary with the response
            if product_id not in product_reviews:
                product_reviews[product_id] = []
            product_reviews[product_id].append(response)

    # Write the dictionary to a JSON file
    with open('review/response.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        json.dump(product_reviews, outfile, indent=4)

def add_review(url, consumer_key, consumer_secret, product_id, review_data):
    wcapi = API(
        url=url,
        consumer_key=consumer_key,
        consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
        version="wc/v3"
    )

    response = wcapi.post("products/reviews", review_data).json()

    return response
```

Despite going through the documentation three times, I'm still encountering an issue that I can't seem to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [product review properties on the official WooCommerce API documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-reviews), you can see that it does not support the `meta_data` field.